# Can't parse a String into Date with a device while everywhere else it's ok

Tags: ios, swift

Here is my method:

```
func dateFromString(dateString: String) -> NSDate? {
    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(abbreviation: "GMT+01")
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "M/d/yyyy hh:mma"

    return dateFormatter.dateFromString(dateString)
}
```

When I try to parse this String : `let date = dateFromString("11/16/2015 5:04am")` I get `date == nil` ONLY on my `iPhone 5 8.4`. Everywhere else (`iPhone 6 9.1` and any simulator version) it's ok.

Any idea how this might be possible?

Comment: Seems weird.  Can you confirm that this happens on a device with those specs, or just on the Xcode simulator.  I'm thinking we could narrow it down to a simulator issue at least..

Comment: Use     `dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mma" `

Comment: Yes it doesn't work ONLY on the `iphone 5 8.4` while it's fine on the `iPhone 6 9.1` and any simulator version/device. Changing the `dateFormat` like `"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mma"` doesn't change the problem.

Comment: Try to set the locale: `dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX")`

Comment: It fixed it indeed. Thanks. But the problem was maybe somewhere else. I tried with specifying a locale, it was ok. Then I tried without, then it wasn't ok again. Then I thought, okay let's try to change the locale on the phone. It was on Australian locale, changed it to a random locale and then it worked without specifying the locale the formatter. I tried to put back to Australia locale and it was still working. As it's an old iOS version, maybe it was a bug that has been fixed since. Just in case, I'll keep the locale in the formatter.